# Creating a finished product with STM32 platform

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I have the STM32 discovery board and I used it with external components to make a simple project. Now my question is: where do I go from here, how do I go from my breadboard + STM to one sleek PCB design with the STM32 platform?

Comment: You copy the parts of the dev board you need, plus the external components, into your own schematic. Layout the PCB. Populate the PCB. Done.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: As short as it is, that's a good answer -- go cut & paste that into an answer box, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the design drawn up in some PCB design software some free choices include but not limited to:
[Eagle](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/free-download)
[KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/)

There are plenty of tutorials ([this one specifically for STM32 in kicad](https://vivonomicon.com/2018/05/05/your-own-hardware-designing-an-stm32-development-board/)) on how to start this process and produce a board.
You draw up the schematic, draw up the footprints for each part (or find a library that someone else has drawn up) then draw up the PCB which replicates the design of the schematic with PCB artwork. *Make sure that you double check the design, and improper design means extra cutting and soldering of wires on the board after its manufactured)

Once the design done you send the pcb files to a manufacturer, (Like PCBway or oshcut) and they send you back some PCB's. You will then either need to send this to an assembler with the parts, or you could hand solder them yourself (also plenty of tutorials like [this one](https://hackaday.com/2021/02/02/learn-bil-herds-diy-surface-mount-assembly-process/) out there) .

Comment: Think you mean oshpark!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So it's basically like rebuilding the microcontroller kit. Thanks for the clarification. Are there packs that include all the individual components so I could solder them or would I have to source all the components individually? I'm pretty new to all of this

Comment: I am very familiar with Kicad so thank you for the link to the tutorial

Comment: There are services that will buy the components and assemble the board  (and more expensive), if you don't then you have to buy the components, buy them (from a distributor like digikey) kit them (label them) and send them to the assembler. If you want components assembled, you will have to supply them with a bill of materials (BOM) which lists the components and designators (each component needs a unique designator

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill mark this as the answer

Comment: Just a recommendation to others who stumble upon this thread.  KiCAD is the way to go.  Digikey is backing up the project with superb tutorials on YT, and doesn't do what Eagle (formerly free) software does: Limit your size, charge you for commercial use or hold your designs hostage on their servers.  The Digikey/KiCAD combo is a match made in heaven for hobbyists.  They make their money by selling you parts not software, and they make it easy to assign parts from their catalog to your design, including footprints.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pre-made modules with STM32 processors on them. They come on a small PCB suitable for installing pin headers. They are like the Arduino Nano, but you don't have to use the Arduino framework. They are programmable via SWD.

Search for STM32 "Bluepill" or "Blackpill".

Example video:

*Blue-pill STM32 Programming Using ST-LINK V2 Dongle*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgR3uM21y7o